# Attempting to implement a hash table in Unity/HLSL compute shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I tried to implement a hash table in Unity/HLSL compute shader that has an int vector as the keys, and a uint as the index to a buffer, which serves as the head reference of a single linked list. I ended up having a race condition in insertion and a deadlock in lookup. What can I do to fix this? Here's the code.

```
#define CELL_EMPTY 2147483647    // value=CELL_EMPTY when Cell is empty
#define GRID_EMPTY int3(2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647)

struct Cell
{
    int3 grid_pos;
    uint value;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<Cell> table;     // hash table
uint num_cells;

uint calc_grid_hash (int3 grid_pos)
{
    // some large primes
    const uint p1 = 73856093;
    const uint p2 = 19349663;
    const uint p3 = 83492791;

    uint n = p1*grid_pos.x ^ p2*grid_pos.y ^ p3*grid_pos.z;
    n = n % num_cells;

    return n;
}

uint grid_lookup (RWStructuredBuffer<Cell> table, int3 grid_pos)
{
    uint slot = calc_grid_hash(grid_pos);
    while (true)
    {
        if (all(table[slot].grid_pos == grid_pos)) return table[slot].value;
        if (all(table[slot].grid_pos == GRID_EMPTY)) return CELL_EMPTY;
        slot = (slot + 1) % num_cells;
}

void grid_insert (int3 grid_pos, uint value)
{
    uint slot = calc_grid_hash(grid_pos);
    while (true)
    {
        if (value == CELL_EMPTY) break;

        // TODO: Race condition here will create multiple slots for the same key!
        int3 old;
        InterlockedCompareExchange(table[slot].grid_pos.x, CELL_EMPTY, grid_pos.x, old.x);
        InterlockedCompareExchange(table[slot].grid_pos.y, CELL_EMPTY, grid_pos.y, old.y);
        InterlockedCompareExchange(table[slot].grid_pos.z, CELL_EMPTY, grid_pos.z, old.z);

        if (all(old == GRID_EMPTY) || all(old == grid_pos))
        {
            // (Put the value to the top of the linked list with InterlockedExchange)
            break;
        }

        slot = (slot + 1) % (uint)num_cells;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you cannot change an array atomically, I think this is not able to solve.

Comment: Thank you, Shingo. I guess you are right.